# Search String for name and log the name for each occurrence using for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm currently making a small program that will run through a string and find an exact match of my name and then push that into an empty array as many times as my name occurs. I am having problems working through the logic in order to get my `for` loops to work properly here is the code I have at the moment.

As you can see I'm not sure what to put in my `for` loops. Any insights on how to solve this logic would be most appreciated. I would also like to apologize if my code makes you want to poke out your eye balls. O.*

```
var text = "This is a Christopher string with Christopher inside of it complicated. The string Coner is fairly long Christopher.";

var myName = "Christopher";

var hits = [];

for(/* ??? */) {
    if (text.search(myName) === true) {
        // If we find it, push name into empty array
        for(/* ??? */) {
            hits.push(text(myName));
        }
    }
}
if( hits === 0){
    console.log("Your name was not found");
}   else{
        console.log(hits);
    }
```

Comment: FYI, if you wanted a quick way to do it without loops: `text.match(/Christopher/g).length` will [give you the number of times](http://jsfiddle.net/4ha39kzs/) the word appears.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use regex instead:

```
var hits = text.match(/Christopher/g);

if (hits.length == 0) {
    console.log("Your name was not found");
} else {
    console.log(hits);
}
```

**UPDATE**

As of you want to use variable as search condition, this is the way how to do it:

```
var condition = "Christopher";
var regex = new RegEx(condition, "g");

hits = text.match(regex);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, WAY less code and it logs perfectly. I didnt know it would automatically convert hits into an array.

Comment: Is there a way to use a variable instead of just typing out my name?

Comment: Super awesomesauce @RyanB! Stack helping to make me a better developer every day!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to search the string for your name.

```
for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
    alert(str[i]);
}
```

This example should print the letter in the string. And to find your name you should replace the alert with an `if(str[i]) === 'C'` statement. If that is true you should check for the next character (H) and continue like that. Eventually if the name is complete add it to `hits[]`.

Comment: Yes, but not just leave it at that. I need it to find it every time it occurs. And for every time it occurs push it into the array. I originally had the program go through each character and match it with the 'C' and then add the characters after that equal to myName.length. but with that I had an array of 44; for each character. Im wanting to get it to be an array of 3 items. My name 3 times, then log it.

Comment: `hits.push("Christopher")` will add the whole name to the array and not as seperate charactars.